# Can I fix my universal meat grinder which leaks when I make cranberry orange relish

Tags: equipment, grinding

'Tis the season for cranberry orange relish, but what a mess!

The source of the leak:  where the handle meets the barrel of the grinder.  Is there a gasket there that can be replaced?

Comment: Could you maybe show us a picture of grinder in question and point us to the leak?

Comment: The pressure shouldn't be very high on the back end of the screw, so a little lard back there to tighten up the clearance might be all you need.